# Firefox flickering when using CSS "filter: drop-shadow()"

Tags: css, firefox, html5-video, css-filters

**Firefox flickering when using CSS "filter: drop-shadow()"**

**This is the CSS:**

```
.glow {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 50px rgba(26, 100, 243, 0.25));
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 50px rgba(26, 100, 243, 0.25));
  transition: all 0.33s ease-in-out;
}

.glow:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 50px rgba(26, 100, 243, 0.75));
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 50px rgba(26, 100, 243, 0.75));
}
```

**GIF on how it looks like on Firefox (unexpected behavior)**
https://i.gyazo.com/4b74faab24bea75198a9c2323e2b0b2f.mp4

**GIF on how it looks like on Chrome (expected behavior)**
https://i.gyazo.com/c4fff9b1e954723aca3230aae2579f02.mp4

It seems to work fine whenever the video above is not interacted with, in other words paused. If I hover my mouse over the video and play the video, it constantly flickers like shown above.

How can I fix this?

I've tried adding -webkit-filter but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Video?What video? I suspect the code you have shown isn't enough for us to see the problem. Please could you add whatever is needed to make it into a runnable snippet which definitely shows the flickering. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.